# 2 potentiometer working as 1

Tags: potentiometer

I am by no mean an expert in electronics. But I am an active hobbyist in RC equipment for last 15 years.

I am on a project that has always been on my mind but never got to do it. But here is the day ! So long story short.. I am modifying a gamer's steering and pedals set to work with RC cars.

It is already done and working beautifully but on my throttle side of the project I am using only the throttle pedal to control (throttle up, brake and reverse). What I want to achieve is to effectively use the brake pedal to brake and reverse.

I know I have got to use 2 potentiometers to act as only one. Like 50% of the range on the throttle and the other 50% on the range on the brake pedal. Now i am utterly confused with it.

If you don't know how an RC transmitter works for throttle and brakes I am more than willing to give my best explanation for it.

Throttle channel work as

- 50% = neutral
- 50% to 100% = throttle up
- 0% to 50% = brake

Now to reverse you have got to fully brake, let the brake off to neutral and brake again.

Is there a wizard here that can point me how to do so?

Comment: Excuse me for asking, but your profile gives no clue. Is English your first language?

Comment: No english isnt my first language. But why do you ask? I just sign in i am a fairly new user ?

Comment: OK. Your English was just a little strange - but not bad. I've tidied it up a little.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user presses both pedals? Or do you not care (that will make this easier)?

Comment: I would like to think that if user presses both pedal it will just be like neutral. As of now i dont really care about that. If it is a big problem afterward i will adress the issue.

Comment: What is the voltage range on the potentiometer? Measure between GND and the wiper. Give a voltage reading for minimum, centre and maximum. Add the information to your question (not in the comments).

Comment: How does this potentiometer connect to the rest of the circuit? with two wires, or with three?

Comment: Okay. I seriously never tought to have answers this fast. As soon as i am home i will do this. Sorry for my bad english transistor. I do my best.

Comment: Potentiometers have three wiper but uses only 2 wire on 2 wipers.

Comment: Add a photo. They translate much better!

Answer (score 1):

Just to let you know that this has been solved. Thanks to all for your help. Here is what i have done.

- soldered the two neutral pots wiper to each other
- soldered wiper 1 to wiper 3 on the other pots and 3 to 1 obviously
- solder the three wire coming from the transmitter himself to throttle pots ( any should do the trick ) following wire order....
- set each pots to neutral when pedal is in stock position
- adjust throttle trim accordingly

And here we go it works flawlessly! Simple enough.

Now i want to say that the pots used all of the three wipers on my transmitter,  but originaly in the steering wheel pedals they were using only two. My confusion started here.

Thanks again everyone you are all awesome !

Answer (score 0):

Realistically this is probably best addressed by building a custom transmitter (or at least data encoder) with a microcontroller which can implement the mixing (or more exactly, range/mode switching) you desire, potentially with a fair bit of customization and complexity.

The actual on-air signalling schemes of most contemporary hobby RC sets have been reversed and published by members of the community, both in detail and in the form of Arduino and/or embedded C (typically ARM) code.  Typically these operate an SPI connected digital radio IC - nRF24L01 or semi-compatible, A7105, etc.

If you don't want to deal with the actual *radio* aspect, another approach is to build your own encoder which generates a multiplexed PPM stream of all channels to inject into the "trainer" or "buddy box" port of a transmitter.

If you really want to do things in the analog realm, you could possible get limited functionality with op amps summing the output of the two.  Actually wiring the pots in effective series will be a bit interdependent - the closest you can come is to connect the wiper of one to an end terminal of the other, and then use the outer end terminals of the pair, but there will be interactions there which may not be what you seek.